# How to get a subset of keys-value from a file with universe of key value pairs

Tags: perl

I have a file with key value pairs separated by whitespace. The first column in the file is the key and the rest of the columns are the value. In other words, each key may have an array for a value.

I'm only interested in the values of certain keys in the file. I have an array with the keys I'm interested in. What's the best way in perl to create a hash with only the subset of key/value pairs that i'm interested in?

Here's what I have thus far:

```
foreach my $line (@{$file_arr_ref}) {
    my $sub = substr( $line, 0, 1);
    if(($sub ne "#") and ($sub ne "")){ #omit comments and blank lines
        my @key_vals = split(/\s/, $line);
        if $key_vals[0] eq "key_i'm_interested_in_1" or $key_vals[0] eq "key_i'm_interested_in_2" {
            insert_into_hash();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more optimal way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a hash from the array with keys you need.

```
my @keys_i_need = ('key_1', 'key_2', 'key_3');
my %keys_i_need = map {$_ => 1} @keys_i_need;

foreach my $line (@{$file_arr_ref}) {
    my $sub = substr( $line, 0, 1);
    if(($sub ne "#") and ($sub ne "")){ #omit comments and blank lines
        my @key_vals = split(/\s/, $line);
        insert_into_hash() if(exists $keys_i_need{$key_vals[0]});
    }
}
```

Comment: this looks right. I always forget that you need to put things into a hash when you want to do  "object in list/array" semantics like in python/ruby.

Comment: I think if you have later version of Perl you can do something like this: insert_into_hash() if($key_vals[0] ~~ @keys_i_need); But I prefer more general code, not version specific.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when one is looking for the existance of something, the first data structure one should think of is a hash.

However, if the list of items is short, an array might be sufficient as well by using [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html).

```
foreach my $line (@{$file_arr_ref}) {
    next if $line =~ /^$/ || $line =~ /^#/;  # Omit blank lines and comments

    my @key_vals = split /\s/, $line;

    next if ! grep {$key_vals[0] eq $_} qw(key_one key_two key_three);

    insert_into_hash();
}
```

Also note, if you're going to be iterating on all the lines of your file, that it might be better to do it in the form `while (<$fh>)` instead of loading them all into an array first.